# Which doctype is reccommended by W3C itself for mobile Websites?

Tags: html, xhtml, mobile-website, w3c, web-standards

Which doctype is recommended by W3C itself for Mobile Websites?

And what is the correct doctype code of that which is valid too?

Comment: This question is not really programming related: flagging for migration to webmaster.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the W3C has made a recent statement on the matter.

The state of mobile devices today is such that you should use the same Doctype as you use for the rest of your site (which should be one that triggers standards mode, likely HTML 4.01 Strict or HTML 5)

Comment: But what about XHTML MP, Basic etc?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/ is not very old W3C Recommendation 23 November 2010

Comment: Mobile devices are designed to deal with "The Web" not "A simplified version of the web".

Comment: I just found this list http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/comparison-xhtml-mobile-profile-and-xhtml-basic it's very confusing , lots of doctypes.

Comment: @David Dorward - You mean we should consider Mobile, Desktop, Tablets same in terms of Doctype, right?

Comment: Yes. For that matter, in many cases you should deliver the same site to them (with media queries to provide different styles for small screens). (I, for one, am fed up with being redirected to the mobile homepage of a website when I follow a link from Google to a specific article).

Comment: But  I don't like to use media queries for some reasons http://www.cloudfour.com/css-media-query-for-mobile-is-fools-gold/ and it's very hard to give good experience on all while keeping performance of website

Comment: @David Dorward: Yup, just as mobile websites are designed to work with "Mobile Devices", not "A simplified version of computers". More seriously, the fact that some websites use incorrect redirects is definitely a problem, but assuming that a mobile device can load a regular page at an acceptable speed is frequently. It's not only a problem of layout; it's also a problem network speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing for many phones use XHTML MP.

If you are targeting high end Android phones/iPhone just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of mobile phone.
If I were you Id pick [XHTML Basic 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/) for WAP phones and HTML5 for smartphones.